# On defense, can I place the camera directly behind me?

Tags: madden-15

I'm playing on PS4.

The "change view/camera" button is supposed to be up and down on the D-pad. On offense, this is no problem, the camera is always directly behind you so it zooms fine.

But on defense the camera is (to my knowledge, by default unless I screwed something up setting up the game initially) still centered behind the offense. I can still use the up/down buttons to change camera. It zooms like it originally did on offense (as intended, no issue here). I can also get it to swing around to focus behind my selected player at an angle, but I find the angle pretty awkward and not-so-easy to play with.

I had played this about a year(?) ago and I'm almost positive you could center the camera directly behind your player on the defensive side (or maybe even the defense as a whole, similar to the offense camera, but opposite). Am I missing something or simply remembering it wrong?

The same desired camera view I'm looking for is what is used during the training/drills for defense (such as strafing/tackling drills). It seems odd they would allow you to train with one camera view, and have you play with another...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking for a few days now, and I don't see a way that this is possible.
I was probably just remembering only the training modes and not actually any actual franchise games.

Viewing modes seem to be limited to varying levels of zoom, and a broadcast type of camera, but nothing centered behind the defense.